# Can I modify the self invoked javascript function property from outside

Tags: javascript

I need to modify the self invoked javascript function from outside of this function.
I have counter in the self invoked function, it is working fine in the plugin. But when i need to change the counter from out side. it is not able to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: the code please...

Comment: (function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  var counter = 1;
})( jQuery );

I need to modify the counter from outside of this script

Answer (score 0):

Changing function properties from outside might be doable, but it's pretty much goes agains the idea of functions.

In my opinion - unless you will publish your code so say otherwise - you might be attempting the solution from the wrong direction.

Try to share the problem you are trying to solve, and not the solution you cant implement.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This seems more like a comment than a real answer

Comment: (function( $ ) { 'use strict'; var counter = 1; })( jQuery ); I need to modify the counter from outside of this script.

Comment: why not from inside?

Comment: it is on the wordpress plugin file, i am just modifying it from the outside for adding an additional function. The plugin will work normal only after modifying this counter

Answer (score 0):

i have assigned the self invoked function to a variable and set some return value from the function.

```
var assigned_variable = (function( $ ) {

  function test_function(counter){
    "add your code for changing the counter"
  }

  return {
    test_function : test_function,
  }

})(jQuery);

function Innerfunction(counter){
  assigned_variable.test_function(counter);
}
```

Now we can access the Innerfunction from outside of the file. We can predefine the  required changes in the "test_function" for the variable counter